# How to send multiple types of classes into Spring stream source

Tags: jackson, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I upgraded my spring stream from 1.3.0 to 2.1.2 and the default serializer was changed from Kyro (deprecated) into Jackson.

I have a kafka topic that more than one type of messages can be sent to. With Kyro I used to deserialize it into Object.class and then cast it to the relevant type of class.

With jackson I can't achieve this functionality, because I have to specify the type of class I want to deserialize to in advance, otherwise, it's been deserialized into a string.

I tried to find an example but couldn't find anything. Any ideas how can I achieve the same functionality? I want to make it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hints to the Jackson encoding so it is decoded to the right concrete type:

`@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So56753956Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56753956Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            output.send(new GenericMessage<>(new Bar("fiz")));
            output.send(new GenericMessage<>(new Baz("buz")));
        };
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
    public static abstract class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public Foo() {
            super();
        }

        public Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getName() + " [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class Bar extends Foo {

        public Bar() {
            super();
        }

        public Bar(String bar) {
            super(bar);
        }

    }

    public static class Baz extends Foo {

        public Baz() {
            super();
        }

        public Baz(String bar) {
            super(bar);
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
com.example.So56753956Application$Bar [bar=fiz]
com.example.So56753956Application$Baz [bar=buz]
```

See [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. You don't need to specify "include" and "property" as they are the defaults though

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Kryo if you want. You can just add it manually using `@StreamMessageConverter`- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-user-defined-message-converters.

With regard to "With jackson I can't achieve this functionality, because I have to specify the type of class. . ." - that is not accurate since the type of the class gets picked up from the signature of the handler method and it is transparent to you as a user.